# Rotate the volume knob in html5 with createJS

Tags: html, html5-canvas, createjs, gsap

I want to create volume knob using HTML5 and CreateJS. It is almost done. you can see this on following url

```
http://www.urbantruanthosting.co.uk/radiosimulator/testpage.html
```

but it is moving on every event of js. And I want to rotate on mouse's pressmove event on both side and currently it's moving clockwise, how can I rotate it in reverse. Please give me suggestion.

Thanks in advance.

and I have used following code.

```
var bmp = new createjs.Bitmap(image).set({
                            scaleX: 1,
                            scaleY: 1,
                            regX: w / 2,
                            regY: h / 2,
                            cursor: "pointer",
                            x: 305,
                            y: -90,
                            rotation: -55
                        });

                        bmp.regX = bmp.image.width / 2;
                        bmp.regY = bmp.image.height / 2;

                        var movieClip = new createjs.Container();
                        movieClip.addChild(bmp);
                        imageContainer.addChild(movieClip);

                        /*add events to enavle the knob to moveclockwise START*/

                        bmp.addEventListener("pressmove", function (evt) {
                            TweenMax.to(bmp, 5, { rotation: 270, repeat: -1, ease: Linear.easeNone });


                            if (headerCnt == 0) {
                                audioElement.play();
                                screen.src = 'images/header_5.jpg';
                                headerCnt = 5;
                                screenImage.set({
                                    image: screen
                                });
                            }
            stage.update();

                        });
```

Answer (score 1):

This is where trigonometry comes in handy. Check out the following [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MLSnK/). Using the Math.atan2 function, we can calculate the angle of the mouse pointer relative to the center of the dial. Then, we convert radians to degrees and set the rotation of the dial.

```
dial.addEventListener("pressmove", function(e){
    console.log(e);

    //Calc Angle
    var adj = e.stageX - dialHolder.x;
    var opp = e.stageY - dialHolder.y;
    var angle = Math.atan2(opp, adj);

    angle = angle / (Math.PI / 180);

    dial.rotation = angle;
});
```

Note: The regX and regY points might be slightly off which is why the dial wobbles a bit.

Comment: Looks like you've made some progress. You may want to try something more like this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MLSnK/11/)  to make it a bit more user friendly. Notice it is just based on movement on the x axis and prevents overturning and underturning.