# Rotate image around it's center using easeljs/canvas/javascript while image remains on the starting position

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, easeljs

I found many questions/answers regarding this issue, but none using easeljs and javascript

So what I want is to rotate the image on the center, not on the 0,0 coordinates of it. I actually managed doing this with regX and regY (http://www.createjs.com/Docs/EaselJS/classes/DisplayObject.html#property_regX), but then the image is drawn out of place (a bit left-up from where it should be).

So my image turns whichever way I want, but is a bit out of place, which is wrong. Image should stay on place, just turn itself and that's it.

Any ideas/suggestions welcome.

If I was unclear, ask for more info please.

I add a player image like this:

```
player = new createjs.Bitmap("../images/player.png");

player.x = X;
player.y = Y;   

stage.addChild(player);
```

where X and Y are some coordinates on canvas. 
If I try to rotate this image on key press with this line for instance:

```
player.rotation = 90;
```

this turns the image for 90 degrees right. So he is facing right now, which is correct and he is on the same spot he was before. BUT if I try to make him face left (with -90), what happens is seen on the pictures below:

[image: player starting position]

[image: what happens when i try to turn him left]

Player started as shown on the first picture. When turning him for -90 degrees, he moves up one lane (picture 2).

So i found out about regX and regY (see link above) and used them like this:

```
player.regX = playerSize/2;
player.regY = playerSize/2;
```

where playerSize is the picture size in pixels. 
This does the job about turning the player correctly on spot, but something else ends up wrong - the player position. This is the picture of starting position when regX/regY are used:

[image: wrong position(should be one move down and to the right]

As you can see, there is some space between the player and "the wall" on the bottom. Player should be positioned one spot down and to the right (as a circle in relation to player on picture 2)

Am I missing something?

This is the image I am using (its white-ish because of the dark background in my game):
[image]

FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/PsychicSaw/MLSnK/24/
Uncomment the lines with regX and regY and see what happens.

Thank you

Comment: Add a Fiddle or at least some code please!

Comment: @SimonPlus, added some code/explanation - hope it helps a little?

Comment: If you can provide your image as well, I can throw a sample fiddle together.

Comment: Your code looks good from what we can see. I am suspicious of the image and I'm wondering if it has extra transparent padding that is throwing everything off. I have [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19910619/1842531) from a while back that has [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MLSnK/) that demonstrates rotation on a regX/regY point. You might want to check that out.

Comment: @Lanny I added my player (ship) image. (its 20x20 px, its better seen on the black background)

Comment: @Andrew I checked your fiddle: that looks good-but my problem remains. I get the image to rotate, but unfortunately it is not on the same position as it is if I don't use regX/regY or your code. I don't have a problem calculating the angle; it's just the position of the whole image that is not correct. Your note in that answer says: "Note: The regX and regY points might be slightly off which is why the dial wobbles a bit." -> i think this might be my issue? When my image is moving and rotating for instance, it wont move in a line -> it will kinda "wobble" as you suggested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your supplied fiddle, I have updated the code to the following to fix the jumping around on rotation. You can see it running on the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MLSnK/26/).

```
var ship;
var canvas;
var stage;
var direction = "up";
var shipHolder;

// add keyboard listener.
window.addEventListener('keydown', whatKey, true);  
// create a new stage and point it at our canvas:
canvas = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);

createPlayer();

createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", tick);
createjs.Ticker.setFPS(20);


function createPlayer(){
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXszc.png";

    var shipSize = 20; // 20x20 px is the image
    ship = new createjs.Bitmap(img);

    shipContainer = new createjs.Container();
    shipContainer.addChild(ship);

    // he starts at the bottom center of the canvas
    shipContainer.x = canvas.width / 2;
    shipContainer.y = canvas.height - shipSize;

    // uncomment to see ship position then
    ship.regX = 10;
    ship.regY = 10;
    ship.x = 10;
    ship.y = 10;

    stage.addChild(shipContainer);    
}

function manageDirection(){
    if(direction == "left"){
        ship.rotation = -90;
    }
    else if(direction == "right"){
        ship.rotation = 90;
    }
    else if(direction == "up"){
        ship.rotation = 0;
    }
    else if(direction == "down"){
        ship.rotation = 180;
    }
}    

function tick(event){
    // draw the updates to stage:
    manageDirection();
    stage.update(event);    
}    

function whatKey(event) {
    switch (event.keyCode) {
        // left arrow
        case 37:
            direction = "left";
            break;
            // right arrow
        case 39:
            direction = "right";
            break;
            // down arrow
        case 40:
            direction = "down";
            break;
            // up arrow 
        case 38:
            direction = "up";
            break;
    }
}
```

Notice the ship has been positioned at x:10 y:10 to account for the offset registration point. Also, by adding it to a `Container`, we are able to rotate the ship on a center registration point, and position it with a top/left orientation by setting the x/y on the Container instead of the ship.

Comment: This does rotate it, yes: but I didn't have problems rotating it with regX/regY actually - the position where it started is my issue. thanks for fiddle - see this: http://jsfiddle.net/MLSnK/19/

Comment: About Note2: ok, so that is the real issue - i didn't know that the offset of the x/y occurs and stays. I thought the offset is just to rotate, and then not applied to image forever. I just need to rotate without moving the ship where it was before (as in my fiddle with those regX/regY). So, if I DONT use regX/regY then the rotation is totally wrong and if I DO use regX/regY, the starting position is not as it should be

Comment: Correct, I realized I misunderstood your question a bit. I think Note 2 should address the issue you are experiencing.

Comment: Did you provide the correct fiddle link there in Note 2? I don't see any container there? Or am I mis clicking something?

Comment: It was there, see edit for a more obvious link. SO could stand to make the links stand out a bit more IMHO.

Comment: haven't found the fiddle with the container included: still - i tried to put the image into it with creating container, then adding image to it as a child, but the position is still not ok. Maybe I am setting container x/y wrong, or regX/Y?

Comment: And unfortunately i failed doing a fiddle with keydown event to show you my exact situation - it just wont work there

Comment: Sorry about that, I've fixed the link.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44910/discussion-between-andrew-and-user1524316)